# exec segfault of trivial C program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, execl

Running a trivial program within gdb, that forks and execl a client.  The execl line (while inside inferior 2 in gdb) gives the process ID "is executing new program" and then immediately seg faults.

Code to that point follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) {
/* Create socket pair for communication with server, and fork/exec the server code */
  int ret;
  int fd[2];
  ret = socketpair( AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0, fd );
  if( ret < 0 ) {
    perror( "Unable to create initial socketpair for qrServer" );
    return -1;
  }
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    char arg[4];
    bzero( arg, 4 );
    close(fd[1]);
    sprintf( arg, "%d", fd[0] );
    char* filename = "child";
    ret = execl( filename, filename, arg, NULL );
```

Just for the sake of completeness, child program begins as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) {
/* Create socket pair for communication with server, and fork/exec the server code */
  if( argc < 2 ) {
    perror("Usage: argv[0] <file descriptor>");
```

Any ideas?  I get nothing, just the seg fault itself and I get it immediately.

Comment: What is the source line that gets the seg fault?

Comment: `arg[4]` is not big enough.  Also get in the habit of using `snprintf( arg, sizeof(arg), "%d", fd[0] )` to help avoid this kind of fault.

Comment: @SteveSummit "*...  is not big enough.*" probably not the case, as the expected values for the two FDs would be `3` and `4`.

Comment: @alk Evidently I'm blind this morning, better go eat something and stop commenting.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Cheers, just having my evening beer ... ;-)

Comment: Maybe the execl is failing because "child" is in the current dir, which is not the search path, but difficult to say if this results in a seg fault without seeing more code.

Answer (score 2):

From `man execl`:

> The list of arguments must be terminated by a null pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.

So this line

```
  ret = execl( filename, filename, arg, NULL );
```

should be

```
  ret = execl( filename, filename, arg, (char*) NULL );
```

Comment: @Aenid37 If this helps, please let us know.  If it helps, it suggests that (a) you're on a 64-bit platform, but (b) `NULL` is defined as plain `0`.  (Which is perfectly legal, but leaves you vulnerable to this problem.)